# If $\sum a_k^2 /k$ converges, then $1/N \sum_1^{N}a_k \to 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to show that if $\sum a_k^2 / k$ converges, then $1/N \sum_{1}^Na_k \to 0$.

Now, if $a_n \to 0$, then the result follows. But of course $a_n\to 0$ is not a necessary condition for $\sum a_{n}^2/n$ to converge. We might want to use Cauchy-Schwarz to say that $a_k^2/k \leq a_k^4 + 1/k^2$, but of course the inequality is pointing the wrong way. Any ideas?

Comment: @Potato Yes it is, but it could be a typo.

Comment: Buck *Advanced Calculus* 3rd edition, page 235

Comment: I just got a hint, which was to write $a_k$ as $\frac{a_k}{\sqrt{k}} \sqrt{k}$, and use the Schwarz inequality. This gives $1/N \sum_{1}^N \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{k}} \sqrt{k} \leq 1/N \sum_{1}^N (\frac{a_n^2}{k} + k)$. Now the first sum goes to zero clearly, but the second should be $\frac{N(N-1)}{2N}$, I believe, which doesn't converge. So I'm still thinking.

Comment: I don't think you got the inequality right...

Comment: @Potato How so? I was trying to employ $ab \leq a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Usually you apply Cauchy to the entire sequence. See my answer below.

Comment: Hmm, that only shows the limit is bounded, sorry. I'm not actually sure what was meant by that hint.

Comment: @Potato: I think it's a bad hint...

Comment: @blabler Yes. You saw you error when I tried it! :(

Comment: @Potato: I know! Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the sum at $k = \sqrt{N}$.

If $\sqrt{N} < k < N$ then by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
\sum_{\sqrt{N} < k \leq N} a_k \leq N^{1/2} \cdot \bigg ( \sum_{\sqrt{N} < k \leq N}
a_k^2 \bigg )^{1/2}
$$
And notice that
$$
\sum_{\sqrt{N} < k \leq N} a_k^2 \leq N \sum_{N > k > \sqrt{N}} \frac{a_k^2}{k}
= o(N)
$$
because $\sum_{k > \sqrt{N}} a_k^2 / k = o(1)$.

If $k < \sqrt{N}$ then
$$
\sum_{k \leq \sqrt{N}} a_k \leq \bigg ( \sum_{k \leq \sqrt{N}} k \bigg )^{1/2}
\cdot \bigg ( \sum_{k} \frac{a_k^2}{k} \bigg )^{1/2} \leq C N^{1/2}
$$
with $C = (\sum a_k^2 / k)^{1/2}$.

Combining the two sums we conclude that
$$
\sum_{k \leq N} a_k \leq C N^{1/2} + o(N) = o(N)
$$
This is the desired claim. Note that we could have splitted at any $k = f(N)$ with $f$ going to infinity.

Comment: Wow, I am very impressed by this solution. Thank you for posting it. It is very educational.

Answer (score 6):

By your condition, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $m$ such that when $N\geq m$

$\dfrac{a_{m+1}^2}{m+1}+...+\dfrac{a_{N}^2}{N}<\epsilon $

By Cauchy one has

$(a_{m+1}+...a_{N})^2<(\dfrac{a_{m+1}^2}{m+1}+...+\dfrac{a_{N}^2}{N})(m+1+m+2+...+N)$.

so,

$(a_{m+1}+...+a_{N})^2<\epsilon \cdot \dfrac{(m+1+N)(N-m)}{2}<N^2 \cdot \epsilon \cdot constant$.

When $N$ is big enough compared with $m$,

$\dfrac{(a_{m+1}+...+a_{N})^2}{N^2}<\epsilon \cdot constant$

Therefore the limit in question is zero.

Comment: That works. Essentially the same argument as mine below.

Comment: The only thing I'm worried about is that the constant depends on $m$, and $m$ depends on $\epsilon$.